# Removing TeX Live

Tags: command-line, latex

I want to update my TeX Live 2009 to 2012. I want a fresh install and would like to remove TeX Live 2009 on my ubuntu. How should I remove TeX Live using my terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove Tex Live, type the following in a console:

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive
```

Comment: It gives me "Package texlive is not installed, so not removed". But I am still able to compile my tex files using pdflatex command?

Comment: Type `sudo apt-cache search tex*` then show us the resulting packages

Comment: Ok. I did sudo apt-get remove texlive-* and not pdflatex doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For me, LnxSlck's solution seemed somehow insufficient. I then did a `apt-get purge texlive-base` (though not sure if I should have) and then `apt-get autoclean` and then I was totally texlive free.