# Removing TeXLive Installation (installed from ISO)

Tags: uninstall, latex

I have downloaded `texlive2017-20170524.iso` from http://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/Images/.

If I install it via `sudo ./install-tl`, how can I remove it from my system later on when I don't want it?

Will I only need to follow the answer at [Removing TeX Live](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195772/removing-tex-live)?

(`sudo apt-get remove texlive`)

Since I didn't install it via `sudo apt-get install texlive`, I'm not sure if it applies

Answer (score 1):

Just `rm -rf` the directory where you installed TeXLive (watch out for typos!) and revert any manual changes you may have made such as altering your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The problem is, I do not know where `sudo ./install-tl` installs to

Comment: The installation directory is chosen by you when you install, so you should know what it is...

Comment: By the way, note that it is not necessary to run the install script with `sudo` (which means you should not do it). Instead, give yourself write permission to the installation directory, and run the install script without `sudo`.

Comment: I get to choose the install directory when I `./install-tl`? Anyway, I am having running the script (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/986646/installing-texlive-from-iso)

Comment: @fkraiem I bet that the vast majority use the default path without thinking about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

When a package that is in the repos is relatively current. I recommend using the normal package management methods. Using the official repos or well maintained ppa's allows you to receive future updates with minimal effort. When the target system is air gapped, [apt-offline](https://askubuntu.com/a/166257/723193) is a viable method to manage packages.

Downloaded installers may or may not include uninstall scripts. If the software doesn't it can be difficult to properly remove all of the components. However you can manually uninstall by looking into the install script to find where the components were installed. If you are not familiar with the language of the installer, Perl in this case, mostly look at the comments.

In the case of the `install-tl` in [install-tl-unx.tar.gz](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Source/). The comments on lines 1393-1401 list "Environment variables and default values on UNIX". The install dir is listed as `/usr/local/texlive`. The user config files should be in `~/.texlive2017/`, leaving them likely will not cause any issues. `rm -rf /usr/local/texlive` should remove the program. Your `PATH` variable may be altered to include `/usr/local/texlive`, however that is just an informed guess.

```
# Environment variables and default values on UNIX:
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX         /usr/local/texlive   => $tex_prefix
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXDIR         $tex_prefix/2010     => $TEXDIR
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFSYSVAR    $TEXDIR/texmf-var
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFSYSCONFIG $TEXDIR/texmf-config
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFLOCAL     $tex_prefix/texmf-local
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFHOME      '$HOME/texmf'
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFVAR       ~/.texlive2010/texmf-var
#   TEXLIVE_INSTALL_TEXMFCONFIG    ~/.texlive2010/texmf-config
```

Comment: This does not answer the question; downvoted and flagged.

Comment: I downloaded an "offline" version for reasons. I can look through the install script, but it is 95 KiB (way too long for me to read line by line manually) - I can upload it for you and you may go through it if you like