# Installing TeXLive from ISO

Tags: software-installation, texlive

I have downloaded `texlive2017-20170524.iso` from http://muug.ca/mirror/ctan/systems/texlive/Images/.

and tried to mount it with both "Open with archive mounter" (by right-clicking on it) and also "Open with --> Disk image mounter"

They are both successful in mounting.

When I `cd` to the mounted location and run `./install-tl` (also tried `./install-tl`), it gives me this error:

```
TeXLive/TLUtils.pm did not return a true value at ./install-tl line 54.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./install-tl line 54.
```

Here are the first 60 lines of `install-tl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# $Id: install-tl 44407 2017-05-18 21:25:39Z karl $
# 
# Copyright 2007-2017
# Reinhard Kotucha, Norbert Preining, Karl Berry, Siep Kroonenberg.
# This file is licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2
# or any later version.
#
# Be careful when changing wording: *every* normal informational message
# output here must be recognized by the long grep in tl-update-tlnet.
#
# TODO:
# - with -gui pop up a transient window showing:
#      testing for compressed archive packages ...
#      testing for uncompressed live system ...
#      testing for network access ...
#      loading tlpdb, this can take some time ...
#   (that, and maybe some others can be done with the waitVariableX
#   thingy as described in the Perl/Tk book in the chapter that can be
#   found on the net)   (Werner 28.10.08)

my $svnrev = '$Revision: 44407 $';
$svnrev =~ m/: ([0-9]+) /;
$::installerrevision = ($1 ? $1 : 'unknown');

# taken from 00texlive.config: release, $tlpdb->config_release;
our $texlive_release;

BEGIN {
  $^W = 1;
  my $Master;
  my $me = $0;
  $me =~ s!\\!/!g if $^O =~ /^MSWin/i;
  if ($me =~ m!/!) {
    ($Master = $me) =~ s!(.*)/[^/]*$!$1!;
  } else {
    $Master = ".";
  }
  $::installerdir = $Master;

  # All platforms: add the installer modules
  unshift (@INC, "$::installerdir/tlpkg");
}

use Cwd 'abs_path';
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_autoabbrev);
use Pod::Usage;
use POSIX ();

use TeXLive::TLUtils qw(platform platform_desc sort_archs
   which getenv win32 unix info log debug tlwarn ddebug tldie
   member process_logging_options rmtree wsystem
   mkdirhier make_var_skeleton make_local_skeleton install_package copy
   install_packages dirname setup_programs native_slashify forward_slashify);
use TeXLive::TLPOBJ;
use TeXLive::TLPDB;
use TeXLive::TLConfig;
use TeXLive::TLCrypto;
use TeXLive::TLDownload;
use TeXLive::TLPaper;
```

I have also tried copying the contents to my hard-drive (so it is no longer in ISO format), as I have had problems before running applications directly from an ISO. It still gives me the above error.

Question: **How can I install TeXLive to my system using `texlive2017-20170524.iso`?**
(I'd much rather use an offline installer rather than `sudo apt-get install texlive`)

---

Here is what I see on the terminal:

```
Me@Computer:~/Desktop$ cd ~/Desktop
Me@Computer:~/Desktop$ mkdir mountpoint
Me@Computer:~/Desktop$ sudo mount -o loop texlive2017-20170524.iso mountpoint
[sudo] password for Me: 
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
Me@Computer:~/Desktop$ cd mountpoint/
Me@Computer:~/Desktop/mountpoint$ ./install-tl
TeXLive/TLUtils.pm did not return a true value at ./install-tl line 54.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./install-tl line 54.
Me@Computer:~/Desktop/mountpoint$
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `sudo apt-get install texlive` ? If you want to install offline, you could use `apt download texlive` on another PC (with matching Ubuntu version), copy the `deb` files and install them with `dpkg -i`. Would that answer your question?

Comment: @janos it would take too long on my internet to download using `sudo apt-get install texlive`. I have a friend who downloaded `texlive2017-20170524.iso` for me (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370354/150700 contains instructions on how to install, but it does not work for me)

Comment: I do not have this issue on my 17.10 system (with the ISO mounted with `sudo mount -o loop image.iso /mountpoint`).

Comment: I'm on 16.04 LTS and also tried `sudo mount -o loop texlive2017-20170524.iso /mountpoint` to no avail (same error message). I have also verified the hash of the ISO file is the same as the one provided

Comment: @fkraiem I'm not sure, but would this be more appropriate if this question is migrated to https://tex.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Note also that you *do not* need to install the full TeXLive as provided by the `texlive` metapackage, as you will never use 99% of the packages it installs. Installing `texlive-base` is enough to begin with, then install other packages as needed.

Comment: Please be more precise about what you are doing: paste the entire terminal text, including the commands you run and their full output.

Comment: @fkraiem I haven't used LaTeX much yet, but what features will I miss out on? (will pdflatex be included?)

Comment: @fkraiem My exact command and what I see on the terminal has been edited into the post

Comment: `pdflatex` is provided by `texlive-latex-base`, as you can see by trying to run it from a terminal.

Comment: Well, this seems to be a bug in the install script, so yes, it is probably going to get better answers on Tex.SE...

Comment: And by the way, if you want to go the package route, at a minimum you will need `texlive-base`, `texlive-latex-base`, and `texlive-fonts-recommended`. If you install with `--no-install-recommends`, that's 38MB to download. Then if you have missing packages, you can install them later (`apt-file search` is your friend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the file was not properly transferred.

The hash of the file on my friend's computer (who originally downloaded it) has the correct hash.

However, the hash of the file on the transfer medium (and the file on my computer) have the same *incorrect* hash.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question is an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):
your ultimate goal is to *install `texlive` offline*,
and doing it from ISO instead of other alternatives is not a requirement.

If that's the case, then you could consider getting the `deb` files of `texlive` and its dependencies, instead of the ISO.
This should simplify the installation and eliminate your issues in the question.

You can get a list of the URLs and MD5 sums of `texlive` and its dependencies by [running this command on your system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/PrintUris):

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install texlive | grep "^'" | sed -e "s/'//g" | awk '{ print $1, $4 }' > packages.info
```

This will generate a file `packages.info` with the URLs to download and their MD5 sums. It's best if your friend also verifies the MD5 sums after downloading.

Once you have the `deb` files, you can install them with `dpkg -i *.deb` and should be good to go.

That being said, as @fkraiem pointed out in a comment,
using the `deb` instead of the ISO has some drawbacks:

> In the case of TeXLive, I think using the official installer is always better than using .debs (indeed, it's what I use myself), mostly because it allows finer management of CTAN packages and better community support (if you ask a question, e.g., on Tex.SE, it will be assumed that you used the official installer, so the solution might not work if you used the .debs)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @fkraiem it does not answer the *question* as it is asked, it aims to answer the *actual need* of the user. The main goal of the user is installing texlive offline. The user thinks an ISO is the way to go, but there's a better way. This should answer the need.

Comment: "`.deb`s are better than ISO" is just your opinion.

Comment: Also, as I have said in comments to the question, installing `texlive` is a waste of bandwidth and disk space, since the vast majority of the CTAN packages it pulls up will never be used.

Comment: @fkraiem I don't really think that `deb` is better than an ISO in general. It depends on the use case. For the average Ubuntu user, I think `deb` is generally better, don't you think?

Comment: +1, no need to use the iso when the deb file is installed in one line, literally. And @janos, good luck getting half of the recommendations from stackexchange to work if you only download the base :P... unless you are simply drawing text and equations.  It is fairly troublesome to be dealing with packages yourself. And 5GB is not much disk space in modern computers

Comment: In the case of TeXLive, I think using the official installer is always better than using `.deb`s (indeed, it's what I use myself), mostly because it allows finer management of CTAN packages and better community support (if you ask a question, e.g., on Tex.SE, it will be assumed that you used the official installer, so the solution might not work if you used the `.deb`s).

Comment: @fkraiem on my system, the 9 `deb`s that `texlive` brings in add up to 35 MB. I think that's negligible, both in terms of saving bandwidth or disk space (knowing that it will be bigger on disk after expanded).

Comment: @fkraiem I see your point about `deb` vs ISO, and modified my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.